# THoughts on TerraClean vs CarbonClean?

Tags: engine, vw, diesel

I've a 2011 VW Golf BlueMotion that's done about 55K now (and I'm getting about 66mpg at a steady 55mph).  I'm very tempted to go for a TerraClean as opposed to the CarbonClean simply because my local garage offers the service.

But before I go ahead, does anyone have any thoughts about the two? ie "Oh no, forget TerraClean, CarbonClean wins handsdown!" or "Nooooo, don't waste your monies on these two" and if so why?

Comment: Your question is being closed because you're asking peoples opinion, a less opinion based question might be 'what are the benefits of each of these services', from which you can make your own decision.

Comment: In addition to @MooseLucifer's suggestion, it would be good to briefly describe what they are, just a couple of words would probably do it. Or add a link to a web site.

Answer (score 3):

This question will probably be flagged as opinion-based and closed, but I think the main difference between Terraclean and carbon clean is that the former uses a liquid cleaner that is shot through the fuel system while the latter utilizes hydrogen gas through the intake to attempt the cleaning.

TerraClean is a little more invasive but said to be more thorough in its cleaning capabilities. Carbon clean doesn't touch the fuel system so it doesn't clean quite as much as the TerraClean system does. I've never heard anything bad about TerraClean, but that doesn't mean that there aren't bad things being said about it.

Research it a little more, but TerraClean seems to be a more thorough means of cleaning the engine.